# How to add pm2(pmx) in sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js, pm2

I am currently using sails for my project and have integrated pm2 with it.

Documentation says I should include pmx for me to be able to calculate http analysis and capture custom alerts.

http://docs.keymetrics.io/docs/pages/http/ gives instruction for plane nodejs. Where do I include pmx in sails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you had already installed pmx `npm install pmx --save`

After that you will need to update your config/bootstrap.js like following:

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) {
  require('pmx').init({
    http : true
  });

  cb();
};
```